# Why "input-group-append" does not cover its parent height?

Tags: css

I have the following code for a part of an html page:

```
    <form class="input-form">
        <div class="row m-0">
            <div class="form-group col m-0 pr-0">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control  pl-0" placeholder="Search for an item" id="searchInput" value="">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button type="button" class="search-btn">
                            <i class="fontello-icon line-height-2">>&#xe80d;</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

with the following styles:

```
.input-div { 
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
}

.input-form {
  opacity: 0.54 !important;  
  line-height: 1.64 !important;
  letter-spacing: normal !important;
  color: #212121 !important;
  border: none;  
}

.input-form i {
  color: #000;  
  line-height: 2;
}

.search-btn { 
  width: 40px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 4px;  
  line-height: 1.64 !important;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none !important;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
}
```

which yields me the following result:

[result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJcds.png)

Now I want to know how to make "search button" (indeed "input-group-append") to cover the height of its parent div or how to get rid of the extra white space under the "search" button?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add a working fiddle? fiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Can you specify what version/source of bootstrap css you are using?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap v4.1.3.

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't add a working fiddle.